# Android: getting file size of image before sharing it (Intent.ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I successfully wrote an app, [based on this blog post](http://eggie5.com/8-hook-share-picture-via-menu-android), but simpler, which streams an image over HTTP, using a POST request.

What I can't figure out (after searching the web and crawling inside android SDK docs) is, how do I get the size of the image before I share it?

There is only a possibility to open an input stream that I see in the exampkle and anywhere else:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
```

The given blog post example uses `getBytesFromFile(is)`, so one could get the size there, but this is **not** a solution. Some images are huge, while android apps are limited in heap space. I want my app to work for all thinkable sizes of images (not a problem when sharing over Wifi).

Therefor, the only option for me is to "forward" the input stream to some HTTP output stream, which I do and which works. But this approach don't give me the image size before sending it.

Answer (score 26):

You can also check it this way:

```
Uri fileUri = resultData.getData();
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(fileUri,
    null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
long size = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE));
cursor.close();
```

Source:
https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/retrieve-info.html

Comment: I've used this method and problem is that file size get using this code might be wrong

Comment: oh really, i'm interested to know when this happens if you can provide any details.

Comment: This is what I've found while trying to resolve this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68672
This happened to me on single image on Nexus 4 running Android 5.1.1 and have solved it using ParcelFileDescriptor.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == 9991) {

            if (data == null) {
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = null;

            File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());


            try {
                is = cr.openInputStream(fileUri);
                cr.getType(fileUri);
                int size = is.available();
                Log.d(TAG, "Size 151: " + getFileSize(size));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

}

> Here's how I fixed my issue similar to this, this will work for Android API below KITKAT.

```
private static final DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
private static final long MiB = 1024 * 1024;
private static final long KiB = 1024;

public String getFileSize(long file) {


    final double length = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(file));

    if (length > MiB) {
        return format.format(length / MiB) + " MiB";
    }
    if (length > KiB) {
        return format.format(length / KiB) + " KiB";
    }
    return format.format(length) + " B";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just ask the InputStream for the number available bytes to get the file size.

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(uri);
int size = is.available();
```

This worked quite reliable once. Don't know if that still holds true as the result is not guaranteed to account for all bytes in the file.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html:   `"Returns an estimated number of bytes that can be read or skipped:without blocking for more input."`

So that will most likely not get the file size.

Comment: I know.. but at the time of writing during my tests it was always the size of the file.